# How to reuse swagger definition in definitions?

Tags: swagger

Code below:

```
definitions:
  Result:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
  FindUID:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
      data:
        type: object
        properties:
          uid:
            type: integer
            format: int64
  FindUsername:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
      data:
        type: object
        properties:
          username:
            type: string
```

As you can see, the first part of `FindUID` and `FindUsername` is the same as `Result`. How to replace those duplicate code with `Result`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compose definitions using `allOf`, here's a full example where Result is used in FindUID and FindUsername:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: Example API Description
  title: Example Title
  version: 1.0.0
paths: {}
definitions:
  Result:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
  FindUID:
    allOf:
      - $ref: "#/definitions/Result"
      - type: object
        properties:
          data:
            type: object
            properties:
              uid:
                type: integer
                format: int64
  FindUsername:
    allOf:
      - $ref: "#/definitions/Result"
      - type: object
        properties:
          data:
            type: object
            properties:
              username:
                type: string
```

More about this here: https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-4-advanced-data-modeling/ (disclosure: I wrote this tutorial)